# Per environment configurations for Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, serverless

For local development I can get away doing `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ApiKey")` and in my `local.settings.json` file I would have a JSON property `ApiKey: "abc123"`.

But when I publish my function from Visual Studio or from Azure Pipeline into Staging or Production. They should be reading config values as per environment and some from KeyVault as well.

I have worked with Consul on-prem installation and it was a breeze. I am not sure what should be the right approach in case of Azure. Use Azure App Configuration service with labels for environments or go into each function instance and manually add configurations and map some with KeyVault?

Comment: Did my answer help you, or any remaining questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### host.json

You don't need to use a KeyVault to store these secrets.
Open your Function App in the Azure portal, then

```
Settings -> Application Settings -> New Application Setting
```

where you fill in

```
Name: ApiKey
Value: thankscasper
```

and you can access them like you did locally.

#### KeyVault

If you do want to use a KeyVault, then set up a **system-assigned managed identity** for the Function App
[image]

Give the managed identity *get* rights for keys under the KeyVault's access policies

If your stored secret is called `X`, you can access it from the keyvault with

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("X", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For your first solution, I would prefer not to manually enter the configs every time a new function is deployed. Also more than 1 function can be using a certain config. So ideally same config should not be copied for multiple function deployments.

Comment: @Ibrahim, the setting stay there after you upload a new version of the function app. Also, you can use `Advanced edit` option to copy-paste your `host.json` file.

Comment: If more than one function app are using the same settings, it's a good idea to put them in the vault indeed :)